# Copy object properties to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, reflection

I am using this method to copy properties of one object to another and its working fine.
But today i found that its not working for arrays of different object.

please help me in this.

```
public static class CopyClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Copies source object properties to target object properties.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">The source.</param>
    /// <param name="target">The target.</param>
    public static void CopyTo(object source, object target)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo propSource in source.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo propTarget in target.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (propTarget.Name != propSource.Name) continue;
                (propTarget.GetSetMethod()).Invoke(target,
                    new object[] { propSource.GetGetMethod().Invoke(source, null) });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use AutoMapper http://automapper.org/

Comment: Your object is serializable ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check with this function? I am not sure if this is working with Arrays but it sure does with plain members.

```
 public static object ObjectCopyProperties(this object sourceObject, object targetObject)
    {
        if (sourceObject == null || targetObject == null)
            return null;

        var targetInstance = targetObject;
        PropertyInfo newProp;
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in sourceObject.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (prop.CanRead)
            {
                newProp = targetInstance.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name);
                if (newProp != null && newProp.CanWrite)
                {
                    newProp.SetValue(targetInstance, prop.GetValue(sourceObject, null), null);
                }
            }
        }
        return targetInstance;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the following 2 classes

```
public class UserType1
{
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string First { get; set; }
    public Gender Genter { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    public string DontMatchType { get; set; }
    public string Unique1 { get; set; }
}

public class UserType2
{
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string First { get; set; }
    public Gender Genter { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    public int DontMatchType { get; set; }
    public string Unique2 { get; set; }
}
```

and the following code

```
    UserType1 user1 = new UserType1
        {
            Id = 1,
            First = "John",
            Last = "Doe",
            Genter = Gender.Male,
            Created = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
            Updated = DateTime.Now,
            DontMatchType = "won't map",
            Unique1 = "foobar"
        };
    UserType2 user2 = CopyTo<UserType2>(user1);
```

you can see that this mapping function will only map matching name/types

```
public static T CopyTo<T>(object source)
    where T : new()
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentException("surce is null", "source");
    T target = new T();

    source.GetType()
          .GetProperties()
          .Join(target.GetType().GetProperties()
                , s => s.Name
                , t => t.Name
                , (s, t) => new
                    {
                        source = s,
                        target = t
                    })
          .AsParallel()
          .Where(inCommon => inCommon.source.PropertyType == inCommon.target.PropertyType
                             && inCommon.source.CanRead && inCommon.target.CanWrite)
          .ForAll(inCommon => inCommon.target.SetValue(target, inCommon.source.GetValue(source, null), null));
    return target;
}
```

and you can use

```
public static IEnumerable<T> CopyTo<T>(IEnumerable<object> source)
    where T : new()
{
    return source.AsParallel().Select(CopyTo<T>);
}
```

to copy a collection like this

```
    UserType1[] users1 = new[]
        {
            new UserType1
                {
                    ...
                }
        };
    UserType2[] users2 = CopyTo<UserType2>(users1).ToArray();
```

This has the added benefit that it will not needlessly loop all the properties of object B for every property in object A, as its using a join to find the properties in common (by name and type).

Mapping can be tricky. You can get into a lot of situations of name/types and nesting. I would suggest Automapper as jjchiw mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If your object is serializable you can create an extension method which serialize the source object and deserialize it in return

```
public static class CloneExtensions
{
    public static T Clone<T>(this T source)
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsSerializable)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The type must be serializable.", "source");
        }

        if(source == default(T))
            return default(T);

        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        using (stream)
        {
            formatter.Serialize(stream, source);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
}
```